# Advantages of using SQL Server 2008 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

What are the advantages in using SQL Server 2008 Database Project which comes with Visual Studio 2010? When you Google about it, you don't find much details on that. Is it outdated or people have better ways of doing what SQL Server 2008 Database Project can do?

Answer (score 1):

#### Pros

- The data compare functionality makes applying and extracting changes *very* easy, and on numerous objects (both different & same types -- table, view, function, etc).  It will also script out the changes - we use it for versioning scripts.  We've encountered the issue regarding updatable views, which is to be fixed in the next Visual Studio.
- The schema compare functionality is helpful when you want to check data that's different between databases.

#### Cons

- I would *never* use it for SQL development.  It's not interactive like Management Studio, so it's not a wise thing to rely on.
- If you have lots of objects (tables, views, functions, sprocs, triggers), VS can take a while to load.  It's not the Database Project issue, so much as Visual Studio as I'm told -- just too many files.
- CLR support in data compare is questionable (scripting export/import), I have yet to look into this